# Lost Router broadcasting a "Lost Network?"

Tags: networking

So I'm working on a network at this house, and there's two wireless networks being broadcast, both by the last name of the owners implying it is in the house somewhere.  The one router I'm staring at, and have replaced with a *new* network id *(so there is just the one old one now)*.  I asked the owners about the other one, they remember it being installed, but they have no idea where it is and we can't find it.  So, I'm wondering what is the best way to go about finding this device and removing it.  Also it shoots a strong signal everywhere in the house and out, and here in FL in a multi-million dollar house built to hurricane code (solid concrete) that is a hard thing to do, so I want to put the new one there.

Are there any tools or any advice or tips that I can use to track it down?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use a more sensitive signal strength meter.

Comment: Make sure it is not just two bands set up on the same router.

Answer (score 1):

Try Heatmapper  [Ekahau Heatmapper](http://www.ekahau.com/products/heatmapper/overview.html)  If you have a floorplan of the house, it works very well. Even without it is usually a great help.

Answer (score 0):

If you can connect a custom antenna to your laptop WiFi, put a short "stick" antenna inside a longish foil-lined can, like from that one potato chip brand. Then point it in various directions and watch your network strengths go up and down.

Answer (score 0):

Carry a battery-powered laptop over to the breaker box. While watching the signal strength on the laptop, slowly turn off the circuit breakers one at a time. Assuming the breakers are labeled, that should give you an idea what part of the house the router is in. If you manage to cut power to the whole house and it's still broadcasting, that tells you a neighbor has it.